# Last $m$ digits of a sum

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

What is an efficent way (not using any computer programs and such) to find last $m$ digits of some terrible looking sum, for example I don't know
$$1^{1000}+2^{1000}+3^{1000}+\ldots+(10^{1000})^{1000}?$$
And let's say that also $m=1000$. I think I know how to approach this problem, but it seems very hard (rather near impossible) and I would like to find something "nice", if that is even possible. Either way it probably requires some modular arithmetics.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\left(10^{1000}\right)^{1000}$, not $10^{1000^{1000}}$ which is normally interpreted as $10^{\left(1000^{1000}\right)}$

Comment: You want to find $1000$ digits **by hand**??

Comment: @RobertIsrael I think OP wants to find a general algorithm.

Comment: The last $m$ digits of that very last term are all $0$s. $\qquad$

Comment: Ou yes, I'm sorry, edited, it's indeed $(10^{1000})^{1000}$. And yes, general algorithm is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Michael hardy how do you prove that?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN : Actually it does depend somewhat on what $m$ is.  But $10$ raised to a power is always $100000000\ldots0000$, i.e. a $1$ followed by some $0$s. For example, $10^4=10000$.  You can prove that by mathematical induction if you want to be fastidious. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy did you notice that the question is a sum of a lot of dirty numbers and the last number to be added is 10 raise to 10000...000 ?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN : Did you notice that I said "that very last term"?  The very last term was $(10^{1000})^{1000}$. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy ok it seemed like it were the last digits of the answer.

Comment: The number just before $(10^{1000})^{1000}$ is $(10^{1000}-1)^{1000}$, which has $999$ $999$ digits and the last digit of that would be one $1$. A looot of other numbers in that sum has $999$ $999$ digits and that is where the computiation gets ugly (last two digits would not yet be that hard)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "one-size-fits-all" general algorithm, but there are a few principles that may help.  Here are some (please feel free to add more in comments):

1. When dealing with a modulus such as $10^m$, it may help to look separately at its prime power factors, in this case $2^m$ and $5^m$, and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to combine them.
2. Euler's theorem: if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$, then $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.
3. Repetition: $k^x \equiv j^x \mod n$ if $k \equiv j \mod n$.  Thus if $m$ is a multiple of $n$, say $m = c n$, then $\sum_{k=1}^m k^x \equiv c \sum_{j=1}^n j^x \mod n$.
4. Rearrangement: if $\gcd(n,a) = 1$, then 
   $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^x \equiv \sum_{k=1}^n (a k)^x \equiv a^x \sum_{k=1}^n k^x \mod n$$
   so $$(1-a^x) \sum_{k=1}^n k^x \equiv 0 \mod n $$
   Thus if there is $a$ such that $a$ and $a^x-1$ are coprime to $n$, we get $\sum_{k=1}^n k^x \equiv 0 \mod n$.
5. [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) expresses $\sum_{k=1}^m k^x$ as a polynomial in $m$ of degree $x+1$, with constant term $0$.  Of course we need to be careful in using this with modular arithmetic, because the coefficients are rational numbers.

By the way, in the case at hand, using Faulhaber's formula we can solve the problem:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{10^{1000}} j^{1000} \equiv 3 \times 10^{999} \mod 10^{1000}$$

EDIT: 
  Faulhaber expresses $\sum_{j=1}^{10^{1000}} j^{1000}$ as a polynomial in $n = 10^{1000}$ with $502$ nonzero terms, but none of the denominators 
are divisible by $2^2$ or $5^2$, so only the term in $n^1$ has a chance to be nonzero mod $n$: this term is 
$B_{1000} n$ where $B_{1000}$ is the $1000$'th Bernoulli number.
The result is $10^{1000} B_{1000} \mod 10^{1000} = 3 \times 10^{999}$.

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for this great comment. It had been very helpful in my studies. Faulhaber's formula seems very useful and I didn't know about it until now.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general algorithm. You have to find an ingenious approach based on the particular problem at hand e.g. by observing some properties of the terms in the sum.

This reminds me of [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/). There are many problems there, which ask for the last $m$ digits of some large sum. I think they do this just because of that reason: since there's no general algorithm, if you found the last $m$ digits, that means you actually solved the problem, you found a way to calculate the sum. Instead of asking you for the whole large sum (which is a large string), they only ask you to input the last $m$ digits. If you provide the correct last $m$ digits, to them this if enough evidence that you solved the problem.